# How to set a property value which is depend on another property value in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have 2 entities:

```
Ad: id, type, enable(boolean)
Type: id, name (1: abcd, 2: efgh)
```

I want at Ad Admin when I choose type == abcd, 'enable' property will be set to true. If it's efgh, 'enable' will be set to false and then save into DB. How can I do? I'm new with Symfony and here is my code:

Type Entity:

```
   /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;
```

Ad Entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $enable;

    /**
     * @var Type
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\App\Entity\Type")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="restrict")
     */
    private $type;
```

This is my AdAdmin.php

```
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper){
        $formMapper
             ->add('type')
             ->add('enable');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to see the `enable` field on the form, you could use a prePersist/preUpdate method to achieve this.

```
public function prePersist($object)
{
    if ('abcd' === $object->getType()) {
        $object->setEnabled(true);
    }

    parent::prePersist($object);
}
```

You can read more on having hooks [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/saving_hooks.html).

Alternatively, you could look into form events [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html).